# Nokia QT Creator project, Error installing Qjson.sis

Tags: symbian, qt-creator, nokia, sis, nokia-n8

I am trying to run up an app in release mode on my Nokia N8. When it builds the phones asks me if i want to install it. i press yes and install it to the mass memory. This happens with out a hitch. Then it asks me to install Qjson.sis i choose the same mass memory drive and then it starts to install. This is when i get a message that reads "Update Error" 
this happens when i install it to both the mass memory and the system memory. Any suggestions? im running win7 with the latest qt creator. The N8 is running PR1.0 not the newer PR1.1

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the QJSON executable (.dll) is already installed on the device, but under a different package and/or UID. 
Best way to get around this is to re-build QJSON with a different UID, and ensure the new UID is appended to the executable name (e.g. qjson_0x20030000.dll). In this way you can avoid update errors.